# Dapper building parameter list

Tags: c#, dapper

I have this class:

```
public class Parameters
{
    public string UserId {get;set;}
    public string OrgId {get;set;}
    public string Roles {get;set;}
}
```

It gets deserialised from a JSON string. So some of the properties are `null`.

What are the best ways to build up the params list to pass to Dapper.

At the moment my logic for building up the params string to tag on the end of the SQL statement goes like this :

```
var parameters = string.Empty;
var parametersObj = new { };
if (query.Parameters != null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.Parameters.UserId))
    {
        parameters = string.Format("{0} UserId = @UserId", parameters);
        // parametersObj.UserId = 
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.Parameters.OrganisationIdentifier))
    {
        parameters = string.Format("{0}, OrganisationIdentifier = @OrganisationIdentifier", parameters);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.Parameters.Roles))
    {
        parameters = string.Format("{0}, Roles = @Roles", parameters);
    }
}

var sqlString = string.Format("exec {0} {1}", query.DbObjectName, parameters);

conn.QueryAsync<dynamic>(sqlString, )
```

As you can see with the `parametersObj` I was going with the `JavaScript` way of dynamically building an object. If I did do this with `dynamic` instead of an object - will it still work?

example:

```
var parameters = string.Empty;
dynamic parametersObj = new { };
if (query.Parameters != null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.Parameters.UserId))
    {
        parameters = string.Format("{0} UserId = @UserId", parameters);
        parametersObj.UserId = query.Parameters.UserId;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.Parameters.OrganisationIdentifier))
    {
        parameters = string.Format("{0} OrganisationIdentifier = @OrganisationIdentifier ", parameters);
        parametersObj.OrganisationIdentifier= query.Parameters.OrganisationIdentifier;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.Parameters.Roles))
    {
        parameters = string.Format("{0} Roles = @Roles", parameters);
        parametersObj.Roles= query.Parameters.Roles;
    }
}

var sqlString = string.Format("exec {0} {1}", query.DbObjectName, parameters);

conn.QueryAsync<dynamic>(sqlString, parametersObj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the second example will work when you change

```
dynamic parametersObj = new {};
```

to

```
dynamic parametersObj = new ExpandoObject();
```

and the query to

```
conn.QueryAsync(sqlString, new 
{
    UserId = parametersObj.UserId,
    ...
};
```

NOTE: filling in the dynamic object like

```
conn.QueryAsync(sqlString, parametersObj);
```

will raise the error

> Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched

Comment: Yeah I got there in the end, did use this solution - because my initial specifications changed. But you are right I think

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything: just pass your object *as the parameters*. Dapper will only pass in properties/parameters that it can identify in the query... and even if it passed them all in: it understands null.

The object is fine.

```
...QueryAsync(sql, query.Parameters)...
```

Comment: `query.Parameters` is an `IEnumerable<>` class that is `public class Parameter { public string Name {get;set;} public string Type {get;set;} public string Value {get;set;}` and is deserialised from `JSON`. So it doesn't quite fit the structure I expect `QueryAsync` is asking for?

Comment: @CallumLinington then how does `query.Parameters.UserId` make sense?

Comment: I've changed the model since I posted the question. So I guess with the new model it won't work. I have another question about Dapper and Unit Testing that I will post.

Comment: @CallumLinington I was basing my answer on the question asked ;p